# font-display unknown property wordpress GoDaddy

Tags: css, wordpress

Recently I've been trying different methods to improve my site performance, and as I found one of the being `font-display`.

As I read about it, it is part of the @font-face rule.

[image]

The warning: 
`Unknown property: 'font-display'`

What should I do in this case? Been looking around for a solution but haven't found any yet.

Comment: Why do you think this property is affecting your site performance? It is just a warning within browser stating that it doesn't support this property.

Comment: How exactly are you getting this error? It sounds like simply a validating routine that is outdated, but does it cause problems? Does it prevent things from working?

Comment: @Morpheus I've been looking for improvements regarding the site's speed. One of them being First Contentful Paint which seems to be higher than it should be and one of the solutions I've found was the one above.

Comment: Mr Lister I'm getting it right after writing it inside @font-face rule. Yeah, it seems it does not make any changes regarding First Contentful Paint which I want to load faster.

Answer (score 0):

Godaddy may say that it is an unknown property, but once it is online, it doesn't matter anymore. Just keep going with your code.

Comment: Yeah, thought of that too but it doesn't change anything, maybe I did not find the 'good' solution for my problem.